# How to add more data to a generated dataset

Tags: r

I would like to make one more addition to the code below. Note that the `All` dataset does not include only 05/07 and 06/07. However, I would like to add somehow to the `All` dataset. In this case both `coef` and `Result` would have the same value, which is the `coef` value, so the final output table would look like this:

```
date2      Category  coef   Result
  <date>     <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2021-06-30 FDE          4      0
2 2021-06-30 ABC          1     -1
3 2021-07-04 FDE          6      3
4 2021-07-05 ABC          3      3
5 2021-07-06 ABC          6      6
```

Executable code below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- structure(list(date1 = c("2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28","2021-06-28"), 
                      date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05","2021-07-06"), 
                      Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC","ABC"), 
                      Week = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Sunday","Thursday"), 
                      DR1 = c(4, 1, 6, 3,3), DR01 = c(4, 1, 4, 3,2), DR02 = c(4, 2, 6, 2,2), 
                      DR03 = c(9, 5, 4, 7,3), DR04 = c(5, 4, 3, 2,3), DR05 = c(5, 4, 5, 4,3), 
                      DR06 = c(2, 4, 3, 2,2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

df2 <- structure(list(date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05","2021-07-06"), 
                      Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC","ABC"), coef = c(4, 1, 6, 3,6)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

v1<- df1 %>%
  select(starts_with("DR0")) %>% names %>%
  paste0("coef-",.)

All<-left_join(df2, df1, by = c("date2", "Category")) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("DR0"), ~ coef - .)) %>%
  select(-Week, -DR1) %>%
  rename_at(-c(1:4), ~v1)%>%
  relocate(date1)

All<-All %>% 
  mutate(across(date1:date2, as.Date)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(starts_with('coef-'), values_to = 'Result') %>% 
  filter(date2 - date1 == as.numeric(str_sub(name, -2))) %>% 
  select(-date1,-name)
> All
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  date2      Category  coef Result
  <date>     <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2021-06-30 FDE          4      0
2 2021-06-30 ABC          1     -1
3 2021-07-04 FDE          6      3
```

**New database to test with 6 dates**

```
df1 <- structure(list(date1 = c("2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"), 
                      date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05","2021-07-10","2021-07-11"), 
                      Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC","ABC","ABC"), 
                      Week = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Sunday","Thursday","Wednesday"), 
                      DR1 = c(4, 1, 6, 3, 3, 1), DR01 = c(4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4), DR02 = c(4, 2, 6, 2, 2, 1), 
                      DR03 = c(9, 5, 4, 7,3, 3), DR04 = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 8), DR05 = c(5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5), 
                      DR06 = c(2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df2<- structure(list(date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05","2021-07-10","2021-07-11"), 
                      Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC","ABC","ABC"), coef = c(4, 1, 6, 3, 6,1)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

**New database to test with 8 dates**

```
df1 <- structure(list(date1 = c("2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28", "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"), 
                      date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05","2021-07-10","2021-07-13","2021-07-20","2021-07-22"), 
                      Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","FDE"), 
                      Week = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Sunday","Thursday","Wednesday","Saturday","Sunday"), 
                      DR1 = c(4, 1, 6, 3, 3, 1,2,4), DR01 = c(4, 1, 4, 3, 2, 4,1,4), DR02 = c(4, 2, 6, 2, 2, 1,2,2), 
                      DR03 = c(9, 5, 4, 7,3, 3,3,2), DR04 = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 8,2,2), DR05 = c(5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5,4,4), 
                      DR06 = c(2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5,4,2),DR07 = c(1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5,4,5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df2<- structure(list(date2 = c("2021-06-30", "2021-06-30", "2021-07-04", "2021-07-05","2021-07-10","2021-07-13","2021-07-20","2021-07-22"), 
                      Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","FDE"), coef = c(4, 1, 6, 3, 6, 5, 11,14)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  date2      Category  coef Result
  <date>     <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2021-06-30 FDE          4      0
2 2021-06-30 ABC          1     -1
3 2021-07-04 FDE          6      3
4 2021-07-05 ABC          3      3
5 2021-07-05 ABC          3      1
6 2021-07-10 ABC          6      6
7 2021-07-13 ABC          5      5
```

Comment: Are you looking for `merge(df1, df2)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update III: Now it should work!!! (Removed prior code)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = c("date2", "Category")) %>%
  select(-c(Week, DR1)) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("DR"), ~ coef - .),
         across(contains("date"), ymd),
         datedif = parse_number(as.character(date2-date1)),
         across(starts_with("DR"), .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'DR0', 'DR_')}")
         ) %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Result = if (str_c('DR_', datedif) %in% names(.)) get(str_c('DR_', datedif)) else coef) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(date2, Category, coef, Result)
```

```
date2      Category  coef Result
  <date>     <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2021-06-30 FDE          4      0
2 2021-06-30 ABC          1     -1
3 2021-07-04 FDE          6      3
4 2021-07-05 ABC          3      1
5 2021-07-10 ABC          6      6
6 2021-07-13 ABC          5      5
7 2021-07-20 ABC         11     11
8 2021-07-22 FDE         14     14
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The output is correct, but I've now tested it for a database that has 6 dates instead of 5, and it doesn't generate the result for the last date. I wouldn't want this restriction. I inserted the new database in the question  for you to test. Note that when running for this new database, 11/07 does not appear in the output table. I will always test databases with more dates, so it would be interesting not to have a restriction for generating the output table. Thanks again!

Comment: Another thing: there you specified `DR01:DR06`. However, it can have more than to `DR06`, is it possible to insert `DR01 :` to the last column of the database?

Comment: could you please check your code @TarJae, I run it and it's not generating. Another thing: I saw that you generated the output table, but for the day 11/07, the `Result` value would have to be equal to the `coef`, as it is on 05/07 and 10/07.

Comment: That's it, I just don't understand why the `Result` value is wrong for 11/07. It would have to be the same `coef` value, that is, `1`. Do you have any idea why? In this case, for all dates after 04/07, the `Result` value is equal to the `coef`. For 05/07 and 10/07 they worked, but for 11/07 it didn't. This is a little weird.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @TarJae. Now the question of generated value is OK. However, I found two inconsistencies when I ran your final code for a database with two more dates than the one you tested and unfortunately these two dates didn't show up in the output table. Also, I have also inserted the `DR07` column, and when I run your code, it is generating values for 05/07 twice. I inserted in the question for you to see. If you prefer, I can ask a new question about it, because the code you made is well on the way, it just needs some tweaking.

Comment: Ok @TarJae, I will wait. Thanks!

Comment: Do not worry! I know you will make it. If you can't, you've already done 90% of the resolution, so I'll accept your answer anyway.

Comment: Please see my final update and tell me if it is now ok. I searched a new approach without pivoting, and now I think I understand what you want to achieve. With this code it should be possible now!

Comment: Perfect, that's it! I am so grateful that you took the time to resolve this issue. Thank you so!